# Hide decimals in a float in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to hide decimals in my text.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text counterText;
    public float counter;
    public float counter2;
    public Text counterText2;
    public float counter3;
    public Text counterText3;
    public float NSIX;

    private void Start()
    {
        counter = 0;
        counter2 = 1;
        counter3 = 70;
        NSIX = 60;
        counterText.text = counter.ToString();
        counterText.text = (int.Parse(counterText.text) + counter3 / NSIX).ToString();
    }

    public void CLICKTHIS()
    {
        counterText.text = (int.Parse(counterText.text) + counter2).ToString();
    }
}
```

Specifically I want to hide the decimals of `counter`. Is there a way to completely disable decimals in a float? Or is there a way to round the float up or down?

Comment: what does "disable decimal in a float" even mean?

Comment: I mean that when I devide `counter3` with `NSIX` (70/60), the result is 1.1666... in my `counter` and I don't want that. I would like it to just result in 1.

Comment: convert it to int, before dispaying.  or you use a parameter with ToString https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: And. you are not aware of the Math.Round methods or how to cast variables to i.e. int? You also neve rread on how to format output in strings (String.Format, FormatString specification?)

Comment: @TomTom Please be more considerate, the ask and answer to your comment are both reasonable for a beginner. Had a bad day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. Mostly it depend on whether you want to round up or down. If you just want to lose the decimals (i.e. round down) you want https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html:

`Debug.Log(Mathf.FloorToInt(myNumber));`

If you want to round up it's https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Ceil.html:

`Debug.Log(Mathf.Ceil(myNumber));`

There are other ways outside the Unity API such as C#'s native conversions e.g.:

`Debug.Log((int)MyNumber.ToString()));`

Comment: tysm! This worked